# Windows 8.1 BIOS accessing

Tags: bios, windows-8.1

I own Lenova g500 machine. I have installed Windows 8.1 in it. When tried to reboot(to install ubuntu) I am unable to navigate to BIOS(via key, nor usb boot works). When rebooted Windows 8.1 in troubleshooting mode I was unable to view UIEF(UEFI Firmware Settings) access option in it.

Can anyone suggest a way to access BIOS.

UIEF is turned off by default on my machine when I upgraded from 7 to 8.1 after than I was unable to access BIOS.

Comment: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/20256-uefi-firmware-settings-boot-inside-windows-8-a.html

Comment: I have no UIEF menu specified when I reboot..

http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/16535d1360705987-uefi-firmware-settings-boot-inside-windows-8-uefi-3.jpg

Comment: post a picture of what you see.

Comment: I have managed it. Once I turned off UIEF boot(moved to legacy) no more the option of UIEF is displayed on Advanced boot options.